# How to combined first_name and last_name using sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

There are two columns in database as name FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME.i want to join both the name and display in single column. The query which is used by me is given below but it gives error as Incorrect syntax near 'NAME'.

Modify the query:

```
SELECT [CREATED_ON], MUD.PK_ID AS USER_ID, 
(MUD.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + MUD.LAST_NAME NAME) 
AS NAME FROM USER_TABLE
```

Comment: what is the use of `NAME` after `LAST_NAME` in `MUD.LAST_NAME NAME`?

Comment: I HAVE ADDED BY MISTAKE. NOW IT IS WORKING AFTER REMOVING IT.

Comment: if either answer helped you, please accept one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the erroneous 'NAME'. e.g.

```
SELECT [CREATED_ON], MUD.PK_ID AS USER_ID, (MUD.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + MUD.LAST_NAME) 
AS NAME FROM USER_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   [CREATED_ON], 
   MUD.PK_ID AS USER_ID, 
   (MUD.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + MUD.LAST_NAME) AS [NAME]
FROM
   USER_TABLE
```

The parentheses around the expression `MUD.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + MUD.LAST_NAME` are optional.